# Fundamental Understanding of fractions and their Properties.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am quite confused about how fractions can be manipulated within other fractions. For example, $(2 + cot^2x)/(csc^2x) - 1$

Why is it possible to rewrite the expression as $(1/csc^2x) + (1 + cot^2x / csc^2x) - 1$

How did the second fraction acquire the # 1 if $(a+b)/c = (a/b) + (b/c)$

Wouldn't it be $(2/csc^2x) + (cot^2x / csc^2x) - 1$?

Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the general rule is:

> $$\frac{A + B}{C} = \frac{A}{C} + \frac{B}{C}$$

So what they did was:
\begin{align*}
\frac{2 + \cot^2 x}{\csc^2 x} - 1
&= \frac{(1) + (1 + \cot^2 x)}{\csc^2 x} - 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{\csc^2 x} + \frac{1 + \cot^2 x}{\csc^2 x} - 1 &\text{using the above rule}\\
&= \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2 x} \right)} + \frac{\csc^2 x}{\csc^2 x} - 1 \\
&= \sin^2 x + 1 - 1 \\
&= \sin^2 x \\
\end{align*}

Comment: But the 2 is in the "a" position, and they are seperated by the + sign? Why are you allowed to split the two?

Comment: Since $2 = 1 + 1$, we are allowed to replace $2$ with $1 + 1$ at any point in time if we feel like doing so. It seems a bit mysterious though; how did they know to do that? I mean, we could have replaced $-1$ with $42 - 43$ after all. The only thing I can really say here is that the person doing the work must have had a lot of experience with trig identities; they wanted to make $(1 + \cot^2x)$ show up, so they applied wishful thinking and forced it to show up. It's a trick. A similar trick is used when completing the square.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.